# Using $apply() with a component

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use `$apply()` with an angular 1.5 component and I am getting the error that `self.$apply` is not a function.

```
viewTest.controller('viewTest', function ($location) {
    var self = this;
    self.$onInit = function (location) {
    self.$apply()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

to use apply need `$scope` instead of `self`. Because `$apply` is angular js $scope function so you can't invoke it through `this`

```
viewTest.controller('viewTest', function ($scope,$location) {
    var self = this;
    self.$onInit = function (location) {
    $scope.$apply()
    }
});
```

Comment: `setTimeout(function () {
      this.loading = false; 
      $scope.$apply();
    }, 10);` doesn't really update the scope...